# Error while inserting Json array into Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm tring to run following INSERT code in PostgreSQL. I have some Json array objects. When i set them null, it works but when i try to execute the code with json arrays, I'm getting error. I describe the details below:

My insert SQL code:

```
 INSERT INTO vuln
        (pde,
         "pde_id",
         pde_description,
         pde_published,
         pde_published_date,
         pde_valid,
         pde_cwe,
         pde_references,
         pde_vu_products,
         pde_eval_has_ex,
         pde_vu_products_has_inc_excl,
         pde_impact)

VALUES      ( '{"data_type": "PDE", "data_format": "MITRE", "data_version": "4.0", "PDE_data_meta": {"ID": "PDE-0001", "ASSIGNER": "PDE@xs2.org"}, "problemtype": {"problemtype_data": [{"description": [{"lang": "en", "value": "CWE-20"}]}]}, "references": {"reference_data": [{"url": "http://www.example.com ", "name": "http://www.example.com ", "refsource": "CONFIRM", "tags": []}, {"url": "http://www.example.com", "name": "5707", "refsource": "OSVDB", "tags": []}]}, "description": {"description_data": [{"lang": "en", "value": "asd"}]}}' , 'PDE-0001', 'asd', 'True', '1999-12-30T05:00Z', 'False', 'CWE-20', '[{"url": "http://www.example.com", "name": "http://www.example.com", "refsource": "CONFIRM", "tags": []}, {"url": "http://www.example.com", "name": "5707", "refsource": "OSVDB", "tags": []}]' , NULL, 'False', 'False', '{"baseMetricV2": {"cvssV2": {"version": "2.0", "vectorString": "AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:N/I:N/A:P", "accessVector": "NETWORK", "accessComplexity": "LOW", "authentication": "NONE", "confidentialityImpact": "NONE", "integrityImpact": "NONE", "availabilityImpact": "PARTIAL", "baseScore": 5.0}, "severity": "MEDIUM", "exploitabilityScore": 10.0, "impactScore": 2.9, "obtainAllPrivilege": false, "obtainUserPrivilege": false, "obtainOtherPrivilege": false, "userInteractionRequired": false}}' );
```

I'm getting following error:

```
LINE 4:         '[{"url": "http://www.example.com...
                ^
DETAIL:  Auf »[« müssen explizit angegebene Array-Dimensionen folgen.
```

My table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE public.vu
(
    "ID" integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    PDE json,
    "PDE_ID" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    PDE_published boolean,
    PDE_references json[],
    PDE_impact json,
    PDE_cwe text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    PDE_valid boolean,
    PDE_published_date date,
    PDE_eval_has_ex boolean,
    PDE_vu_products_has_inc_excl boolean,
    PDE_vu_products json[],
    PDE_description text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT vu_pkey PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
)
```

What am i doing wrong? I tried to cast the array objects with json_array_elements(), but it didn't help me.

Comment: Your `PDE_vu_products` and `PDE_references` columns have type `json[]`, not `json`. Is that intended? If yes, then you need to pass an array of json strings.

Comment: Yes i want it as json[] and PDE_references is also json[]

Comment: So what exactly is the desired value, a postgres array of json arrays? A postgres array of json objects? Something else? (Or do you actually want a `json` column with a `check` constraint that ensures the top-level value is an array?)

Comment: I have Json arrays and want to insert these into PDE_vu_products und PDE_references. So i want to store them also as array. I think i have then better performance when i want to search in million records.

Comment: @MichealToru: If you're concerned about performance, your better bet is to normalize and don't use JSON or arrays at all.

Comment: I doubt that it makes any difference. What index are you using?

Comment: Don't use `json[]` use `json` for your column's data type

Comment: @Bergi I'm pretty new to psql. i didn't use any index. i just thought that. then i will change it to json. if you all think so.

Comment: @stickybit I have totally 120K which i have to insert into this table. In another table i have 15M entries. For each entry in 15M i have to check if there is any product in 120M. Isn't it better to use json? I will make the analyse only once.

Comment: Yes, performance is gained through indexing so you need to look into that first. Regarding the difference between `ARRAY['{…}'::json, '{…}']::json[]` and `'[{…}, {…}]'::json`, both might be viable but the former is just confusing.

Comment: @MichealToru: I don't get any details from the numbers you throw around. But I'm quite certain analyzing and normalizing that data upon `INSERT` will make it way easier to work with it later on. Now it seems like you just dump everything as JSON and want to defer the analyzing and normalizing step, which means it has to be repeated over and over again later and possibly also prevents supporting structure like index from being created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to insert a single JSON where the engine expects an array **of** JSON (that's not a JSON array!). Your column `pde_references` is defined as `json[]`. Try to insert the value as an array with a single value:

```
INSERT INTO public.vu
            (...
             pde_references,
             ...)
            VALUES (...
                    ARRAY['[{"url": "http://www.example.com", "name": "http://www.example.com", "refsource": "CONFIRM", "tags": []}, {"url": "http://www.example.com", "name": "5707", "refsource": "OSVDB", "tags": []}]']::json[]
                    ...);
```

The quotes around the Boolean values aren't necessary BTW. You can just write `true` or `false` not `'true'` or `'false'`.